# Softlayer api to [create Archive Transaction] method is not power on the device automatically?

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

Softlayer API  run 'create Archive Transaction' method.

How do you power on the device automatically?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The **createArchiveTransaction** method turns off the server, after the image is created, the server will automatically turn on.

You can verify the server's status with the following method:

```
https://$user:$apiKey@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/$vsiId/getPowerState

Method: Get
```

**References:**

- [SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest::getPowerState](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/getPowerState)